# I created a react-redux authentication using redux toolkit query to fetch data from a node backend that provides a response with an accessToken

Tags: reactjs, api, authentication, jwt, redux-toolkit

For 2days now I have failed to figure out a solution to this problem. My app can handle the authentication when a user logs in but when a user logout and another user login on the same computer the request to refetch the data will not be sent to the backend and the user will login with the previous user's data. I really don't know why its like this yet I clear the redux state on logout. I have read from a number of resources but I don't seem to find a solution.

I tried a few solution that suggestively would clear cache as some sources refered this to cache data not being cleared. I have done a lot of jagons to solve this but unfortunately nothing worked. I am just stack now.

This is my code for apiSlice.js

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:10000/api/v1"

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: `${BASE_URL}/user`,
    credentials: 'include',
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
        const token = getState().user.token
        console.log(token)
        if (token) {
            headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`)
        }
        return headers
    }
})

const baseQueryWithReauth = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
    let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
    console.log(result)
    if (result?.error?.originalStatus === 403) {
        //send refresh token to get new access token
        const refreshResult = await baseQuery('/token', api, extraOptions);
        console.log(refreshResult)
        if (refreshResult?.data) {
            api.dispatch(setCredentials({ ...refreshResult.data }));
            result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
        } else {
            api.dispatch(logOut());
        }
    }


    return result;
}

export const apiSlice = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'authSlice',
    baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
    tagTypes: ['User'],
    endpoints: builder => ({}),
    keepUnusedDataFor: 0,
})
```

And this is my code for authApi.js

```
import { apiSlice } from "./apiSlice";
import { userApi } from "./userApi";


export const authApi = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        registerUser: builder.mutation({
            query: (user) => ({
                url: `/signup`,
                method: "POST",
                body: user
            })
        }),
        loginUser: builder.mutation({
            query: (data) => ({
                url: '/login',
                method: 'POST',
                body: data,
                credentials: 'include'
            }),
            providesTags: ['User']
        }),
        logoutUser: builder.mutation({
            query: () => ({
                url: "/logout",
                method: 'POST',
                credentials: "include"
            }),
            async onQueryStarted(args, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
                try {
                    await queryFulfilled
                } catch (error) {

                }
            }
        })
    })
})
export const {
    useRegisterUserMutation,
    useLoginUserMutation,
    useLogoutUserMutation
} = authApi;
```

This is my userApi.js

```
import { apiSlice } from "./apiSlice";

export const userApi = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getMe: builder.query({
            query: () => ({
                url: `/me?_=${new Date().getTime()}`,
                credentials: "include",
            }),
            transformResponse: (result) => result.data.user,
            async onQueryStarted(arg, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
                try {
                    const { data } = await queryFulfilled;
                    dispatch(setUser(data));
                } catch (error) { }
            },
        }),
    }),
})

export const { useGetMeQuery } = userApi
```

This is my userSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';


const initialState = {
    user: null,
    token: null
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
    initialState,
    name: 'userSlice',
    reducers: {
        setCredentials: (state, action) => {
            const { accessToken, data } = action.payload
            state.token = accessToken
            state.user = data;
        },
        logout: () => initialState,
        setUser: (state, action) => {
            state.user = action.payload;
        },
    },
});

export default userSlice;

export const userActions = userSlice.actions;
```

This is my store.js

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { setupListeners } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query";
import myListSlice from "./features/myListSlice";
import { persistReducer, FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import userSlice from "./features/userSlice";
import { apiSlice } from "./api/apiSlice";


const persistConfig = {
    key: "root",
    storage: storage
}
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    myList: myListSlice.reducer,
    user: userSlice.reducer,
    [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
})
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({ serializableCheck: { ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER], } }).concat(apiSlice.middleware)
})

setupListeners(store.dispatch)
```

This is my Login.jsx code for dispatching functions

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useActionData, useNavigate, useSubmit } from "react-router-dom";
import Logo from "../../assets/images/Logo.svg";
import background from "../../assets/images/background.jpg";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import { loginValidate } from "../../Validations/UserValidation";
import { useLoginUserMutation } from "../../Store/api/authApi";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { userActions } from "../../Store/features/userSlice";
import Spinner from "../../Components/Spinner";

const Login = () => {
  // const loading = false;
  const [loginUser, { isLoading: loading }] = useLoginUserMutation();
  const submit = useSubmit();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const data = useActionData();
  const { setCredentials } = userActions;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
    validationSchema: loginValidate,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      submit(values, { method: "post" });
    },
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      if (data) {
        try {
          const { accessToken } = await loginUser(data).unwrap();
          dispatch(setCredentials({ accessToken, data }));
          navigate("/");
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [data]);
```

This is my Root.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Outlet, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Footer from "../Components/Footer";
import Navbar from "../Components/Navbar";
import Spinner from "../Components/Spinner";
import { useGetMeQuery } from "../Store/api/userApi";
import { userActions } from "../Store/features/userSlice";

function Root() {
  const { token } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { setUser } = userActions;
  const { data: user, isLoading } = useGetMeQuery();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (token === null) {
      navigate("/account");
    }
    dispatch(setUser(user));
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <>
          <Spinner />
        </>
      ) : (
        <div className="bg-black">
          <Navbar user={user} />
          <div className="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between">
            <Outlet />
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Root;
```

Comment: Hello, did you figure this out, I have the same problem and can't seem to find the solution

Comment: useLazyQuery it reloads everytime the page reloads.

Comment: Please just answer your own question instead of putting the code in the comment section

Comment: I have answered it in the answer below sorry for any inconveniences cause.

Answer (score 0):

When you use useGetMeQuery to access the user data, the data will be cached and on the following requests the data will be fetched from cache before making a request and thus it will serve the data from the cache and terminate the request but when you use useLazyGetMeQuery it helps to refetch the data whenever the component mounts and supplying it the adjument false to its trigger which in that case is getUser, it will fetch a user on reload and component mounting but removing false will make the caching possible.

```
 function Root() {
  const { token, user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const [isInitialLoadCompleted, setIsInitialLoadCompleted] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [getUser] = useLazyGetMeQuery();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (token === null) {
      navigate("/account");
    }
    getUser(undefined, false)
      .unwrap()
      .then((response) => dispatch(setUser(response)))
      .catch(() => dispatch(logout()))
      .finally(() => setIsInitialLoadCompleted(true));
  }, [token]);
```